# automatically create new pages with php and mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

still getting my feet wet with php and mysqli, have so much to learn, but at this point this question is one of my most important priorities.

I did some research about this issue but am currently overwhelmed by pretty sophisticated stuff for my level, to be honest. I'd like to find the simplest most efficient way to "automatically" generate a great number of pages each with varying data in it.

the example of page 1's code below is *extremely* simplified, because the actual page actually has a lot more stuff, but the simplified example serves, I hope, to make my point.

```
<?php

$servername = "servername";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$db= "db";

$conn = mysqli_connect("servername","username","password","db");


$query = "SELECT word FROM demo WHERE group=1";
$result = $conn->query($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$word = $row['word'];

echo $word;

?>
```

in my table I have / would have something like 500 entries (records?) in the 'group' column, numbered 1, 2, 3 etc all the way to 500.
for my specific purpose, I absolutely need to create as many online pages as there are groups -- in this example, 500 pages.

page 2's echo would have to refer to group 2, page 3's echo would have to refer to group 3, and so on.

obviously, there's a way to do this without copying and pasting the code 500 times and manually changing the group in each! haha. but what's the simplest way?

thank you in advance for any understanding and help, and either way, have an awesome day.

Comment: Learn about `$_GET` parameters.

Comment: Is `group` a real column name (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)? You shouldn't need 500 pages. Have 1 page that has its content built dynamically. Use a `GET` parameter to know which page the user is on. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: thank you both. i'm gonna look into $_GET parameters and parameterized queries. and no, "group" is not the actual field name. but would that be a problem if it was?

Comment: Yes, `group` is a reserved term in `mysql`. See the linked doc. Everything with the `(R)` is a reserved term, and can't be used unless in backticks (or you could just always backtick).

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, I believe you're waiting to create pages from the database Dynamically. You can use a get variable in the request `http://yoursite.com/page.php?group=1.` 
Then in your code update your query to do:

```
$query = "SELECT word FROM demo WHERE group=".$_GET['group'];
```

That query is insecure, as any user could inject raw mysql into the $_GET['group'] variable.

```
$group = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['group']);
$query = "SELECT word FROM demo WHERE `group`='$group'";
```

This is much safer.

Comment: Redacted. Parameterized queries are what new users should be advised to use.

Comment: This query will have syntax error cuz `group` is a reserved mysql word.

Comment: You should remove your much safer portion before the parameter binding police get here.

Comment: Cleared up the typos. I agree that statements should be used, but that's beyond the scope of answer their question.

Comment: thank you all. i'm gonna do my best. btw thanks for the heads up about mysql injection. i'm reading up on it and other security issues with forms etc, but for my own exercise/learning right now i'm prioritizing trying to solve this 500 pages thing. i'll make sure i have security in place and much more before i take them from private personal demo to public. but i now its gonna take me a while to get this GET variable thing right... one thing at a time

Answer (score 0):

So PHP will look for a file called `index.php` by default in any directory that it accesses. You can place such a file in the root of public_html or www or where ever your site accesses. Now in this file you can do something like:

```
<?php
    if($_GET['group']){ //Make sure you have the var
         $query = "SELECT word FROM demo WHERE `group`=?"; //The query with param
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, query){ // try it out
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $_GET['group']); // bind the data
            $stmt->execute(); //run it
            $result = $stmt->get_result(); // get results

            //use result to echo and stuff
        }
    } else {
        //Do something incase there is not a group specified.
        echo "Nothing here";
    }
?>
```

Now when you go to your site you will get something like 'localhost/index.php' and see Nothing here but if you type `localhost/index.php?group='55'` you will have access to the page 55 data in result.

Comment: thank you so much nerdlyist for the detailed example. in all honesty, i'm still too confused about some basics to think i'll be able to make it work right away. i think i need to study/practice more so i can have an understanding of some of the stuff you all are using in your codes that i don't really understand, but i really really appreciate the input and sample. eventually i'll be prepared to use it properly and with a grip on what everything in the code is and does. thanks again to u all